# Why doesn't the jQuery event ".on" have any event argument

Tags: jquery, html, css, events, undefined

The following code doesn't work:

```js
var moveDownBtnHTML = '<a href="#" class="moveDown"> down </a>',
    moveUpBtnHTML = '<a href="#" class="moveUp"> up </a>';

function reloadBtns()
{
   $(".cats .cat .moveUp").add(".cats .cat .moveDown").remove();
   $(".cats .cat").children("input").after(moveDownBtnHTML + moveUpBtnHTML);
   $(".cat:first-child .moveUp").add(".cat:last-child .moveDown").remove();
}

$( document ).ready(function() {
   $(".cats").on('click', '.moveDown .moveUp', function(evt){
      if(evt.target.attr("class") == ".moveDown")
      {
         var i = $(".cat").index(evt.target.parent()),
             ctm = "<div class='cat'>"+$(".cat").eq(i).html()+"</div>";
                    
         $(".cat").eq(i).remove();
         $(".cat").eq(i).after(contentToMove);
   
          reloadBtns();
      }
      else if(evt.target.attr("class") == ".moveUp")
      {
         var i = $(".cat").index(evt.target.parent()),
             ctm = "<div class='cat'>"+$(".cat").eq(i).html()+"</div>";
                            
         $(".cat").eq(i).remove();
                    
         $(".cat").eq(i - 1).after(contentToMove);
                    
         reloadBtns();
      }
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Categories editor</h2>
<div class="cats">
  <div class="cat"><input type="text" name="cate[]" value="Category 1" readonly/><a href="#" class="moveDown"> down </a></div>
  <div class="cat"><input type="text" name="cate[]" value="Category 2" readonly/><a href="#" class="moveDown"> down </a><a href="#" class="moveUp"> up </a></div>
  <div class="cat"><input type="text" name="cate[]" value="Category 3" readonly/><a href="#" class="moveUp"> up </a></div>
</div>
```

It's normally in a form to make a kind of database with multiple categories which contains data but it isn't very important...

I don't know how to pass a event data information in argument to know which "button" activated the event to know if I need to up the category or if I need to down it. I tested a lot of methods but I finally decided to get back to you. I have just lost 2 days with that form!

I have seen on this forum that in [selector.on(trigger, selector, function(event){}] the event argument will contain a jQuery event. Why doesn't it work?

How can I do it the most simply?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem you had, is that you compare class name with dot on it, and after you re-add the links to go up or go down, don't assign the event clicks. i moved the functionality of links to a function, so after adding the buttons, i re-assign the functionality to the new buttons. to move up, the code needed a little fix, to get the actual position it should be moved.

in jquery to get the element that launched the event you can access it through "$(this)"

if i'm missing something in the answer just comment, and i'll explain.

```js
var moveDownBtnHTML = '<a href="#" class="moveDown"> down </a>',
    moveUpBtnHTML = '<a href="#" class="moveUp"> up </a>',
    template = '<div class="cat"><input type="text" name="cate[]" value="Category __number__"/></div>';

function reloadBtns()
{
   $(".cats .cat .moveUp").add(".cats .cat .moveDown").remove();
   $(".cats .cat").children("input").after(moveDownBtnHTML + moveUpBtnHTML);
   $(".cat:first-child .moveUp").add(".cat:last-child .moveDown").remove();
   assignEvent();
}

function assignEvent() {
    $(".cats .moveDown, .cats .moveUp").on('click', function(){
      var that = $(this); //for precaution $(this) have the object that started the event
      if( that.attr("class") == "moveDown")
      {
         var i = $(".cat").index(that.parent());
         contentToMove = "<div class='cat'>"+$(".cat").eq(i).html()+"</div>";
         $(".cat").eq(i).remove();
          $(".cat").eq(i).after(contentToMove);
   
         reloadBtns();
      }
      else if(that.attr("class") == "moveUp")
      {
         var i = $(".cat").index(that.parent());
         contentToMove = "<div class='cat'>"+$(".cat").eq(i).html()+"</div>";
         $(".cat").eq(i).remove();
         $(".cat").eq(i-1).before(contentToMove);
     
         reloadBtns();
      }
   });
}

$( document ).ready(function() {
   assignEvent();
    
   $('.addnew').click(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       howmany = $('.cats').children().length;
       newcat = template.replace(/__number__/, howmany+1);
       $('.cats').append(newcat);
       reloadBtns();
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Categories editor</h2>
<div class="cats">
  <div class="cat"><input type="text" name="cate[]" value="Category 1" readonly/><a href="#" class="moveDown"> down </a></div>
  <div class="cat"><input type="text" name="cate[]" value="Category 2" readonly/><a href="#" class="moveDown"> down </a><a href="#" class="moveUp"> up </a></div>
  <div class="cat"><input type="text" name="cate[]" value="Category 3" readonly/><a href="#" class="moveUp"> up </a></div>
</div>
<a href="#" class="addnew">Add new</a>
```

Comment: Great, it's working. But if I add a jQuery form to add categories to the .cats div. And I add a button to delete categories... Does the `$(document).ready` execute itself at each modification ?

Comment: the $(document).ready only gets executed when the document is fully loaded, after that, if you add, or remove an element with javascript or jquery, you need to assign the functionality to this new elements.

Comment: i realize that you could do this with "sortable" or "nestedSortable" jquery plugins, adding just drag n' drop functionality. i used nestedSortable on the backend of the site, to sort the images of a slider. it has good functionality to get the order of the elements. you should check it, maybe it will make what you're trying to do easier.

Comment: How can I do that ? Is it possible to run assignEvent(); again ? (it's a big website with a lot of php code ... I prefer not to use plugins :|)

Comment: of course you can, check at the end of the reloadBtns function. each time you reload the buttons, it assigns the functionality. so each time you add a new element, the only thing you need to do is to call the redloadBtns() function, and you're done.

Comment: check the edit, i added a link to add new categories, and a template variable, you can see what i did so you can change it to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

I see several issues:

Change this:

```
if(evt.target.attr("class") == ".moveDown") {
```

to this:

```
if ($(evt.target).hasClass("moveDown")) {
```

Make the same change for your `moveUp` comparison.

Your original line of code could have worked if there was never more than one class on the object AND you removed the `.` from the comparison string.  Remember, the actual class name does not contain a `.`.  That is something you add when constructing a CSS selector.  But comparing to the class attribute would just be the bare string, not a selector string.

But, it's better to just use `.hasClass()` (as shown in my suggested code) and not have to worry about whether there's more than one class name on the object or not.

Then, secondly, it looks like you're completely regenerating your HTML, but not reinstalling the event handlers.  When using event handlers directly attached to DOM elements, if you replace those DOM elements, they will not have any event handlers on them.  The better solution here is probably not to replace your HTML at all, but to just modify it as needed.  But, if you are going to replace the `.cat` HTML, then you have to reinstall the event handlers after you create the new HTML.

---

FYI, in the future, you can help debug situations like this yourself by figuring out what diagnostic code to add.  In this case, it probably would have shown you what was going on if you added this:

```
console.log(evt.target.attr("class"));
```

You may then have seen that there was no `.` in the class name and certainly if there was more than one class name on the object, you would have seen that too.

Comment: Ok ;) I'll use .hasClass next time.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this entire thing can be made simpler if you add a `mover` class to the buttons and simply hide the up/down buttons (first/last) instead of hitting the DOM with a remove/add of those.

Markup:

```
<h2>Categories editor</h2>
<div class="cats">
    <div class="cat">
        <input type="text" name="cate[]" value="Category 1" readonly /><a href="#" class="moveDown mover"> down </a><a href="#" class="moveUp mover"> up </a>
    </div>
    <div class="cat">
        <input type="text" name="cate[]" value="Category 2" readonly /><a href="#" class="moveDown mover"> down </a><a href="#" class="moveUp mover"> up </a>

    </div>
    <div class="cat">
        <input type="text" name="cate[]" value="Category 3" readonly/><a href="#" class="moveDown mover"> down </a><a href="#" class="moveUp mover"> up </a>
    </div>
    <div class="cat">
        <input type="text" name="cate[]" value="Category 4" readonly/><a href="#" class="moveDown mover"> down </a><a href="#" class="moveUp mover"> up </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Code:

```
function showButtons() {
    $('.mover').show();
    $('.mover.moveUp').first().hide();
    $('.mover.moveDown').last().hide();
}
$(".cats").on('click', '.mover', function (evt) {
    var moveup = $(this).hasClass("moveUp") ? true : false;
    var par = $(this).parents('div.cat');
    var n = par.next();
    var p = par.prev();
    if (moveup) {
        par.insertBefore(p);
    } else {
        par.insertAfter(n);
    }
    showButtons();
});
showButtons();
```

Test it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/xxmb41jL/

Comment: It's also a good idea to optimize the code but check the answer who solved my problem... The categories can be changed dynamically. [screen](http://prntscr.com/85byrf) <= look ;)